# How to update the frontend when a new row of data is added to a postgresql database

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I created an email parser that takes an email that comes in, strips it of some data and inserts it into a postgres database. This data is reflected on the frontend. Every time I insert a new row of data from an email I have to refresh the frontend to be able to see the new data. Is there a way to trigger my pre-existing API GET request from the frontend when there is a new piece of data inserted into postgres so that I can see real time data updates on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You have two primary options:

- Use technique so-called long polling, when the frontend requests for some data from the server, server checks whenever there is a new record to send back if there is a record(s) it sends a response if there is not, it keeps the connection opened until the new record appears.
- Use socket connection (bidirectional client-server communication), when the client opens a socket connection and waits for a specific event to be emitted by the server